# Application that monitors the current display

Tags: image-processing

This is a broader question that I am looking for some help on. I am trying to build an application that monitors the current display( the actual display that the user is seeing on his monitor). Very specifically i need to extract data from a specific portion of the desktop (an application is running there), monitor for changes in that part of the screen. I understand the changes would be visual and will need image processing.
Tried google but it has been a nightmare. It picks up keywords like display , monitor, extract and i get unusable results.
It would be really helpful if anyone who has done this before, or maybe if someone cant point me in the right direction.
Thanks! hope i have explained my query well.

Comment: You're looking for a key-logger, I assume. (tut, tut...)

Comment: @RichardDunn If i am not wrong, a keylogger monitors keyboard strokes correct? I am looking to monitor a portion of the screen for changes eg. text changed from login to logout

Comment: Yeah, I was only kidding with ya. I've never worked with display outputs, etc. soz...

Comment: why do you even include "display" into you google search? its an image. who cares where or if it is displayed. processing is the same...

Comment: You could use `nircmd` http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html (see last few entries in table) or similar to grab the screen pretty simply without any code. You could process that with **ImageMagick** quite readily but you'd need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do that for windows, then it is better to look into WINAPI and start digging from here:

[GetWindowRect on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633519(v=vs.85).aspx)

[FindWindow on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx)

[C++ example on Stack Overflow for getWindowRect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18291790/how-to-use-getwindowrect)

[C++ example on Stack Overflow for FindWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16530871/findwindow-does-not-find-the-a-window)

You can enumerate windows, search for particular keywords in titles, update window coordinates by timer. After you will successfully do that, dig here:

['efficiently acquiring a screenshot of the windows desktop' on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292700/efficiently-acquiring-a-screenshot-of-the-windows-desktop)

['How to compare byte to byte of two bitmap screenshots in c++' on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243233/how-to-compare-byte-to-byte-of-two-bitmap-screenshots-in-c?rq=1)

Right after you will successfully acquire screenshot and learn how to detect changes (not to re-process whole image), dig here:

[OCR engine - libtesseract on Github](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract)

[C++ libtesseract API example on Github](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/APIExample)

Happy learning!